# TeXstudio Macro Creation Problem with Spacing

Tags: texstudio, editors

I have been trying to create the following macro in TeXStudio(seen in the picture below):

```
\begin{align*}
    %|
\end{align*}
```

but when I activate it in my tex file I get this:

```
\begin{align*}
(cursor here) 
\end{align*}
```

with no tab before the cursor.  How can I create the macro to include the tab before the cursor.  Also, are there any in depth articles/tutorials regarding macros in TeXstudio?

[image: picture of macro example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a little bit of Javascript ([more detail can be found here](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33)):

```
%SCRIPT
editor.write("\\begin{align*}\n\n\\end{align*}");
cursor.movePosition(1, cursorEnums.PreviousLine, cursorEnums.MoveAnchor);
editor.write("\t");
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks! So I guess there is no way to do it with a simple text replace (not that it matters much, but do you know why the text macro editor does not include spacing)?  Also, where would be a good place to start learning Java Script for the sole purpose of making advanced macros (assuming a fairly strong programming/scripting background?

Comment: @walwb: I don't think I can answer that, the only reason I "learn" Javascript was in fact that to write some fairly simple scripts in TeXstudio. All I did is Googling around.